# How to get or know wsdl of a deployed web service from tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, wsdl

I am learning SOAP/WebService and I have created a project to start with. The project structure is : [image]

I created a WAR and deployed to `apache-tomee-plume-1.7.1`, but the problem is that how to get WSDL address of the WebService.
The code of the file ProductWS.java is :

```
package org.mano.ws;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.mano.ejb.ProductEJB;
import org.mano.entity.Product;

@WebService
public class ProductWS {

       @EJB
       ProductEJB productEJB;

       public List<Product> getAllProductDetails(){
             return productEJB.getAllProducts();
       }

       public List<String> getAllProductNames(){
             List<Product> list=productEJB.getAllProducts();
             List<String> productNames = new ArrayList<>();
             for(Product p:list){
                    productNames.add(p.getName());
             }
             return productNames;
       }
}
```

And Product.java is a POJO class.

Please suggest..

Comment: .../webservcieRootUrl/?wsdl

Comment: Would u please give a descriptive solution ??